# Alinhar elementos de um formulário ao centro?

Tags: html, css, formulário

Como posso colocar os inputs/textareas no centro (mas quero que o label continue na esquerda)?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
form {
    width: 700px;
    color: red;
}
form textarea,input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="publicar"/>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Título"/>
    <label for="info">Seu Texto</label>
    <textarea id="info"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso criando uma class, por exemplo - `alinhamentoCentro`(ou o nome que lhe queiras chamar) e dar-lhe os seguintes estilos: `.alinhamentoCentro {margin: 15px auto;}`.
Depois basta aplicares esta `class` a cada elemento que queres que seja alinhado ao centro.

Tudo junto ficará algo como:

```css
form {
    width: 700px;
    color: red;
}
form textarea,input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.alinhamentoCentro {margin: 15px auto;}
```

```html
<form>
    <input class="alinhamentoCentro" type="submit" name="publicar"/>
    <input class="alinhamentoCentro"type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Título"/>
    <label for="info">Seu Texto</label>
    <textarea id="info" class="alinhamentoCentro"></textarea>
</form>
```